# Concordance Treemap Java

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

I am trying to print out the concordance from a txt file and im using a scanner to read the file below i seem to be have a problem putting the words in the array list

```
public class Concordance 
{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException 
    {
        TreeMap <String, ArrayList<Integer>> concordance = new TreeMap <String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        File myfile = new File ("Caesar.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myfile);
        ArrayList <Integer > integer = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scan.nextLine().length(); i++) 
        {
            String key = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (scan.nextLine().length(i) > 1) 
            {
                if (concordance.get(key) == null) {
                    concordance.put(key, 1))
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Integer> value = concordance.get(key).indexOf(integer);
                    value++;
                    concordance.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(concordance);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two problems, Solution of first problem is here
http://stackoverflow.com/faq
After you have solved your first problem, some one here might be able to solve second problem...Cheers !

Comment: What is `value++` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot compile.

You are trying to put an integer in a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

This is the line:

```
concordance.put(key, 1))
```

Also this line fails:

```
value++;
```

Since value is a collection of `Integer`, not an integer.

This line will always return false at runtime:

```
ArrayList<Integer> value = concordance.get(key).indexOf(integer);
```

Because `integer` is declared as `ArrayList`, and you are searching a collection of Integer.

In general, you have a great confusion between `Integer` and `ArrayList<Integer>`. You are also making calls to `scan.nextLine()` without noticing that it ADVANCES a line each time it is called.